# latest Luna eclipse PDT nolonger gives common function suggestions

Tags: php, eclipse, pdt

I was using helios version of PDT but it was compatible only till `v5.3` so I downloaded latest luna version to get `v5.5` support from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/luna/SR1/eclipse-php-luna-SR1-win32-x86_64.zip).
but after downloading this instead of supporting new functions it stopped showing hints for most of the new/old functions such as `crypt()`,`str_replace()` etc how can I fix this ?

Comment: Actually none of the string functions are suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with dltk (see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=412073)

Steps to fix it:

1. Close eclipse
2. Remove dir: $workspace_loc/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2
3. Run eclipse
4. Wait a moment for reindexing